# How to change color upon clicking radio buttons but using value

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have multiple groups of radio buttons that I want to change color upon being clicked. I am using `name` to change color but when the name of all radio buttons are similar it is counted as one group. I need to split them up.

my code :

```
function getInputValue() {
  var radioObj = document.forms["form"]["tt"];
  for (var i=0; i<radioObj.length; i++) {
    if (radioObj[i].checked)
      return radioObj[i].value;
  }
  alert("No radio button was selected.")
}

function change_it(id) {
  var a = getInputValue();
  if(a=="Bad") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#FFBFBF";
    return false;
  } else if(a=="Good") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFF0";
    return false;
  }
}

<table>
<tr  id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
<td>
 It changes the color in here.
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<form action="#" method="get" name="form">
Group 1
<input type="radio" name="tt" id="1" onclick="change_it();" value="Bad" />Bad </input>
<input type="radio" name="tt" id="1" onclick="change_it();" value="Good" />Good</input>
Group 2
<input type="radio" name="tt" id="2" onclick="change_it();" value="Bad" />Bad </input>
<input type="radio" name="tt" id="2" onclick="change_it();" value="Good" />Good</input>
</form>
```

my porblem is if I change the `name` the colors wont change anymore if I keep the `name` the same then all 4  are counted as one group.

**EDIT**
I want to make it clear that the code I have works perfectly. What I am trying to figure out is how to make it so that the color change is not stuck to using `name` attribute.

Comment: You have `document.forms["form"]["tt"]` hardcoded in. That needs to be dynamic too, if you want to group them

Comment: You're also giving **5** things the same `id`. All `id`s need to be unique

Comment: And `<input /></input>` should be `<input />`

Comment: And all your radio buttons have the same `value`

Comment: how can i make the `document.forms["form"]["tt"]` dynamic? The id's are in while loop using php so they output in groups of two but with different ID's. sorry I didnt mention that. Also your right about the input. but does it not need a `</input>` to close?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I made the edit to reflect your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `class` to group the radio buttons, and give the `td` that you want to be changed the same class. For example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="group1">Change me!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="group2">Change me!</td> <!-- This won't be changed in the below code -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="radio" class="group1" />
```

jQuery:

```
   $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
    var className = "td." + $(this).attr("class");
    $(className).css( "color", "red" );
    });
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvavM/9/)

Comment: this worked as well but i feel i have more flexibility with the answer by enhzflep.

Comment: do i need something special to make this work in  my browser? cause copying and pasting does not seem to work from fiddle.

Comment: @Dev-Ria You need to include jQuery, that is all :)

Comment: @Dev-Ria You can do so by putting `snippet: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head></head>` tags

Comment: figured i was missing a library but even after entering it i am not able to get it to run. here is what I used. any idea what im doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/bEkvuD0d

Comment: @Dev-Ria First of all, put the <script> with the code from my answer inside the `<body>` tags. Second, if that doesn't fix the problem, check your console for any errors or send me a live version of the code

Comment: makes absolutely no sense. I made it exactly how you instruct it and still it doesnt work. I checked console and only error i got was that it couldnt open the above url to googleapis.com but i added http:// and that fixed it. This should technically be working if you test it in a browser, but its not -> http://pastebin.com/5pCVUhNJ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28816/discussion-between-evan-and-dev-ria)

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the trick. I've not addressed the problem previously mentioned, regarding making the text 'tt' dynamic - I've hard-coded them as gp1 and gp2. Each of the radio buttons now have their own id, I've also put the label for each one inside a label tag - this enables styling. All styling is done by targeting the Label tags. I've also attached the function that will handle the onclick event using addEventListener, since doing so allows us access to the `this` variable - it points to the element that triggered the click event. (it also allows other, unused functionality - such as multiple handlers for a single event on a single element and the ability  to selectively remove said handlers)

I've also changed the change_it function. 
It now does the following:

- Get the name attribute of the radio button
- Get the list of elements that have the same name (items in same
  radio-button group)
- Set the className of the `<label>` tag that encloses the clicked
  radio-button and other items in it's group

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    var index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function addClass(element, newStr)
{
    var index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
}

function removeClass(element, newStr)
{
    var index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if (index != 0)
        newStr = ' '+newStr;
    element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
}

function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    var inputList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
    var i, n = inputList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        inputList[i].addEventListener('click', change_it, false);
    }
}

function change_it()
{
    var grpName = this.getAttribute('name');
    var otherElementsInGroup = document.getElementsByName(grpName);

    forEachNode(otherElementsInGroup, nodeItemFunc);

    function nodeItemFunc(element, index, list)
    {
        if (element.checked)
            addClass(element.parentNode, 'checked');
        else
            removeClass(element.parentNode, 'checked');
    }
}

</script>
<style>
label.checked
{
    background: #fda;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="get" name="form">
    Group 1
    <label>Bad<input type="radio" name="gp1" id="rb1" value="Bad" /></label>
    <label>Good<input type="radio" name="gp1" id="rb2" value="Good" /></label>
    <br>
    Group 2
    <label>Bad<input type="radio" name="gp2" id="rb3" value="Bad" /></label>
    <label>Good<input type="radio" name="gp2" id="rb4" value="Good" /></label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well done!! this works perfectly!! i only have one question. Is it possible to use `tr` instead of `Label` because I'd like to have the color of the entire row change. Also I need to use two different colors RED for BAD and GREEN for GOOD. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks, you're most welcome. Sure thing, you can use a td(parent of radio btn) or a tr (parent of parent of a radio btn). In order to get different colours, you may wish to use the addClass function - using the radiobutton's `value` - You would then get `class='checked Bad'` and `class='checked Good'` or some other variation thereof, suitable to your needs. You can then target with `td.checked.Good`, `td.checked.Bad` (or the tr equivalents)